# Popen with PIPE stdout doesn't exit untill Enter is pressed

Tags: python, lxc

When I start a Popen with PIPE stdout, the process doesn't exit untill I press `Enter` (Windows OS, tested with multiple `python` and `lxc` versions)
e.g.:

```
import subprocess as sp

cmd = ['lxc', 'exec', 'remote:container', '--', 'echo', '1']

with sp.Popen(cmd, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE) as proc:
    while True:
        print(proc.poll())
```

prints None None None... (proc.poll() == None when the process is still running) and when I press `Enter` it immediately exits.

The process itself does it's job, nothing wrong there, only this exiting problem. It probably lies within the scope of the utility I'm calling (`lxc`) but is there something I can do to debug this or to circumvent it from the python code?

This call works when it is called during a `py.test` run, when `py.test` captures all output, maybe I can do something similar to what it does?

Comment: The process is inheriting your Python script's stdin. Better to override that if you want reliable/consistent behavior; `stdin=sp.DEVNULL` will work in a new enough Python release. `stdin=open('/dev/null')`, otherwise.

Comment: BTW, a `while True:` busy loop is not particularly good practice, when you could use `proc.wait()` or another call that doesn't return until the process exits. What are you trying to accomplish thereby?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy that helped, thank u very much for the explanation. Now I pass stdin=DEVNULL when capturing stdout and it works perfectly. while True loop is just for the sake of this stripped down debugging example.

Comment: Glad that helped; I'll add an answer to the effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want your process to interact with stdin (a category under which waiting for or responding to input on that handle applies), the best approach to prevent that is to not let it inherit your original Python script's handle (as happens by default with no `stdin` argument passed to `Popen`).

A few ways to do that:

- Add the argument `stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL` (on a new version of Python)
- Add the argument `stdin=open('/dev/null')`
- Add the argument `stdin=subprocess.PIPE`, and then call `proc.stdin.close()`, or `proc.communicate('')` (of course, only if you only want `communicate()`'s other effects).

Comment: FWIW, `subprocess.DEVNULL` exists since Python 3.3, which is hardly "new"!

Comment: Heh. I'm finally reaching the point of acknowledging Python 3 as something other than a newfangled experiment (it's only been what, 11.5 years?)